# Simple Python multi threaded webserver with Asyncio and events called in main function

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a simple Python program that I want to do three things:

- Serve an HTTP document
- Serve Websockets
- Interact with the Websocket data

I am trying to use / grok `asyncio`.  The issue is that I can't figure out how to access data acquired from a function in the main event loop.

For example in my code below I have two threads.

One thread is the HTTP server thread, one thread is the Websocket server thread and there is the main thread.

What I want to do is to print data captured in the websocket receiving thread in the main thread.

The only way I know how to do this is to use Queues to pass data between threads at which point I do not even know what the advantage of using `asyncio` is.

Similarly, it feels weird to pass the event loop to the `serve_websocket` function.

Can anyone please explain how to architect this to get data from the Websocket function into the main function?

It seems like / I want a way to do this without using the `threading` library at all, which seems possible. In an async project I would want to react to websocket events in different function than where they are called.

NOTE:  I know there are other libraries for websockets and http serving *with* asyncio but this is an example to help me understarnd how to structure projects using this paradigm.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import socketserver
import threading
import http.server
import asyncio
import time

import websockets

SERVER_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
HTTP_PORT = 8087
WEBSOCKET_PORT = 5678


def serve_http():
    http_handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", HTTP_PORT), http_handler) as httpd:
        print(f'HTTP server listening on port {HTTP_PORT}')
        httpd.serve_forever()


def serve_websocket(server, event_loop):
    print(f'Websocket server listening on port {WEBSOCKET_PORT}')
    event_loop.run_until_complete(server)
    event_loop.run_forever()


async def ws_callback(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        # How do I access parsed_data in the main function below
        parsed_data = json.loads(data)
        await websocket.send(data)


def main():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ws_server = websockets.serve(ws_callback, SERVER_ADDRESS, WEBSOCKET_PORT)

    threading.Thread(target=serve_http, daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=serve_websocket, args=(ws_server, event_loop), daemon=True).start()

    try:
        while True:
            # Keep alive - this is where I want to access the data from ws_callback
            # i.e.
            # print(data.values)
            time.sleep(.01)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Exit called')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you should not mix `asyncio` and `multithreading` without special need. And in your case, use only `asyncio` tools.

In this case, you have no problem sharing data between coroutines, because they all run on the same thread using **cooperative** multitasking.

Your code can be rewtitten as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import socketserver
import http.server
import asyncio
import time
import websockets

SERVER_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
HTTP_PORT = 8087
WEBSOCKET_PORT = 5678
parsed_data = {}


async def handle_http(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()


async def ws_callback(websocket, path):
    global parsed_data
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        # How do I access parsed_data in the main function below
        parsed_data = json.loads(data)
        await websocket.send(data)


async def main():
    ws_server = await websockets.serve(ws_callback, SERVER_ADDRESS, WEBSOCKET_PORT)
    print(f'Websocket server listening on port {WEBSOCKET_PORT}')
    http_server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_http, SERVER_ADDRESS, HTTP_PORT)
    print(f'HTTP server listening on port {HTTP_PORT}')

    try:
        while True:
            if parsed_data:
                print(parsed_data.values())
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Exit called')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This looks like it is more in the direction of what I want but I should have clarified that I am try to avoid using global variables too.  That's really the jist of what I want to do.  Get the data from the other couroutines in the `main` function without globals.

Comment: You can use any shared object between coroutines. E.g. you can place coroutines as class methods and share `self`. If you want consumer-producer pattern, you can use `asyncio.Queue`

Comment: I see.  And also this `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` part.  Why the value 0.1? Why not 0.001? Why is it necessary at all? Ideally there would be no delay at all between checking for the parsed data.